# How to order this specific Inner Joins?

Tags: php, mysql, join

Right now I'm creating an online game where I list the last transfers of players.

The table that handles the history of players, has the columns history_join_date and history_end_date.

When history_end_date is filled, it means that player left a club, and when it is like the default (0000-00-00 00:00:00) and history_join_date has some date it means player joined the club (in that date).

Right now, I've the following query:

```
SELECT 
    player_id,
    player_nickname,
    team_id,
    team_name,
    history_join_date,
    history_end_date
FROM 
    players
        INNER JOIN history
            ON history.history_user_id = players.player_id
        INNER JOIN teams
            ON history.history_team_id = teams.team_id
ORDER BY 
    history_end_date DESC, 
    history_join_date DESC
LIMIT 7
```

However, this query returns something like (filtered with PHP above):

```
(22-Aug-2012 23:05): Folha has left Portuguese Haxball Team.
(22-Aug-2012 00:25): mancini has left United.
(21-Aug-2012 01:29): PatoDaOldSchool has left Reign In Power.
(22-Aug-2012 23:37): Master has joined Born To Win.
(22-Aug-2012 23:28): AceR has joined Born To Win.
(22-Aug-2012 23:08): Nasri has joined Porto Club of Haxball.
(22-Aug-2012 18:53): Lloyd Banks has joined ARRIBA.
```

PHP Filter:

```
foreach ($transfers as $transfer) {

//has joined
if($transfer['history_end_date']<$transfer['history_join_date']) {
    $type = ' has joined ';
    $date = date("d-M-Y H:i", strtotime($transfer['history_join_date']));
} else {
    $type = ' has left ';
    $date = date("d-M-Y H:i", strtotime($transfer['history_end_date']));
}
```

As you can see, in the transfers order, the date is not being followed strictly (22-Aug => 21-Aug => 22-Aug).

What am I missing in the SQL?

Regards!

Comment: Forgot to mention that. They are being stored as datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are ordering based upon two different values. So your results are ordered first by history_end_date, and when the end dates are equal (i.e. when it is the default value), they are then ordered by history_join_date

(Note that your first results are all ends, and then your subsequent results are all joins, and each subset is properly ordered).

How much control do you have over this data structure? You might be able to restructure the history table such that there is only a single date, and a history type of JOINED or END... You might be able to make a view of joined_date and end_date and sort across that...

---

From what you have in the question I made up the following DDL & Data:

```
create table players (
    player_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    player_nickname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

create table teams (
    team_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    team_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

create table history (
    history_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    history_user_id INT NOT NULL, history_team_id INT NOT NULL, 
    history_join_date DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    history_end_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
);

insert into players VALUES 
    (1,'Folha'),
    (2,'mancini'),
    (3,'PatoDaOldSchool'),
    (4,'Master'),
    (5,'AceR'),
    (6,'Nasri'),
    (7,'Lloyd Banks');

insert into teams VALUES 
    (1,'Portuguese Haxball Team'),
    (2,'United'),
    (3,'Reign In Power'),
    (4,'Born To Win'),
    (5,'Porto Club of Haxball'),
    (6,'ARRIBA');

insert into history VALUES 
    (DEFAULT,1,1,'2012-08-01 00:04','2012-08-22 23:05'),
    (DEFAULT,2,2,'2012-08-21 19:04','2012-08-22 00:25'),
    (DEFAULT,3,3,'2012-08-19 01:29','2012-08-21 01:29'),
    (DEFAULT,4,4,'2012-08-22 23:37',DEFAULT),
    (DEFAULT,5,4,'2012-08-22 23:28',DEFAULT),
    (DEFAULT,6,5,'2012-08-22 23:08',DEFAULT),
    (DEFAULT,7,6,'2012-08-22 18:53',DEFAULT);
```

---

SOLUTION ONE - History Event View

This is obviously not the only solution (and you'd have to evaluate options as they suit your needs, but you could create a view in MySQL for your history events and join to it and use it for ordering similar to the following:

```
create view historyevent (
    event_user_id,
    event_team_id,
    event_date,
    event_type
) AS
    SELECT 
        history_user_id,
        history_team_id,
        history_join_date,
        'JOIN' 
    FROM history
    UNION
    SELECT
        history_user_id,
        history_team_id,
        history_end_date,
        'END'
    FROM history 
    WHERE history_end_date <> "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
```

Your select then becomes:

```
SELECT 
    player_id,
    player_nickname,
    team_id,
    team_name,
    event_date,
    event_type
FROM players
INNER JOIN historyevent
        ON historyevent.event_user_id = players.player_id
INNER JOIN teams
        ON historyevent.event_team_id = teams.team_id
ORDER BY 
    event_date DESC;
```

Benefit here is you can get both joins and leaves for the same player.

---

SOLUTION TWO - Pseudo column. use the IF construction to pick one or the other column.

```
SELECT 
    player_id,
    player_nickname,
    team_id,
    team_name,
    history_join_date,
    history_end_date,
    IF(history_end_date>history_join_date,history_end_date,history_join_date) as order_date
FROM 
    players
    INNER JOIN history
        ON history.history_user_id = players.player_id
    INNER JOIN teams
        ON history.history_team_id = teams.team_id
ORDER BY 
    order_date DESC;
```

Building from @Barmar's answer, you can also use [GREATEST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) to pick the greatest of the arguments. ([MAX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) is a grouping function... not actually what you're looking for)

Comment: Hmm, but this table is serving for "history" purposes to. As I'm listing in each player' profile their history, and I guide me from here. From the SQL I have, am I not able to do a kind of "mix" of both, to get them in a unique "datetime" to be sorted out?

Comment: If the history table was (history_user_id,history_team_id,history_type,history_date) you would have one column for event dates, You still can join to the players table, and you can still restrict based upon type (joined or left).

Comment: Or do you mean you're looking for default left date times to determine group membership in addition to an audit log?

Comment: I've used your second solution, thanks, It works perfectly, but I really don't understand how does it works as I've never used IF's in Selects. Could you explain me the main concept behind that query?

Comment: What's happening is you're using the [IF function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) to calculate a value based on each record as an additional column in your result set, you name the column, and then use that to sort your result set. You could forgo returning the column, and use the calculation directly in the ORDER BY clause (but this way you can see the values). The downside here is that indexes cannot be used to help your ordering (as the calculation is done on the fly), but that only really matters when you get to large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:

```
ORDER BY MAX(history_join_date, history_end_date)
```